# Greek characters not stored in MySQL through Hibernate Wildfly Web App

Tags: java, mysql, utf-8, collation

i have built a Java EE Web Application, which stores some data in  MySQL database.
Data issubmitted by the user via Restful Web Services(AJAX call) and hibernate ORM , using entity Manager's persist() method.

The problem comes with Greek characters, which are stored as "?" .

I changed mySQL character set and collation to utf-8 and utf8_unicode_ci ,
I've tried to insert greek characters by manually inserting records to the database and it worked fine.

So i run the app in debug mode, to see in what form data is handled in code,
and the characters where correct from the time the web service called, until the persist()  method is called.

I am using Wildfly 9.
Do you have any ideas? 
I really don't know what else to try..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just found out the solution!

In Wildfly Configuration -> Subsystems -> Undertow -> Servlet/JSP ->View,

there is an option called "User listener encoding", it has to  be set to true.

[image: Settings: Servlet/JSP]

Comment: I didn't know about you use Wildfly before you update the question. Anyway, glad you solved this issue.  )

Comment: Geez -- how cryptic can they get!

Answer (score 1):

Check that you added in the hibernate settings next:

```
<property name="hibernateProperties">
   <props>
        ...        
        <prop key="hibernate.connection.characterEncoding">UTF-8</prop>
        <prop key="hibernate.connection.charSet">UTF-8</prop>               
        <prop key="hibernate.connection.useUnicode">true</prop>
    </props>
</property>
```

And check that your data source connection url looks like this:

```
jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydatabase?characterEncoding=UTF-8&useUnicode=true
```

Comment: i did both, problem remains :( ... I added the properties in this form:<property name="hibernate.connection.characterEncoding" value="UTF-8"/>.Is it the same this way?any other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution of this issue is to set column attribute sql-type="NVARCHAR" or sql-type="NCHAR" in .hbm.xml file or in column annotation in java entity file.